# How to use PersianDatePicker in Razor?

Tags: datepicker, persian, persian-calendar

I want to use [PersianDatePicker](http://www.dotnettips.info/post/1382/persiandatepicker-%DB%8C%DA%A9-datepicker-%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86-javascript-%DA%A9%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AE-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D9%85%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%DA%A9%D9%86%D8%AF). How can I use it in razor (`EditorFor`) instead of `<input>` since I want to use viewbag as today date, and set the value using `@Model`.

```
 <input type="text" id="Item.FromRequestDate" name="Item.FromRequestDate" onclick="PersianDatePicker.Show(this, '1392/03/22');" class = "form-control form-filter input"  />
```

my base `EditorFor` is as below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.FromRequestDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-filter input" } })
```

**Update:**

**As a solution, I did it as below:**
(I haven't use EditorFor yet.I have wrote the codes below just as alternative and it's not answer)
Now, I use `Item.FromRequestDate`  as name and Id for binding value to model.

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewBag.PersianFromRequestDate" id="Item.FromRequestDate" name="Item.FromRequestDate" onclick="PersianDatePicker.Show(this, '@ViewBag.PersianToday');" class = "form-control form-filter input"  />
```

and in controller I have

```
ViewBag.PersianFromRequestDate = item.FromRequestDate;
```

for sending the value from controller separately (and not in model), and

```
        var now = PersianDateTime.Now;
        var today = now.ToString(PersianDateTimeFormat.Date);
        ViewBag.PersianToday = today;
```

for today value. Attention that you should use today Viewbag in single cote sign, even if you have send it as string from controller: `'@ViewBag.PersianToday'`

Comment: You don't need to convert the date and pass it as a ViewBag. `PersianDatePicker.cshtml` will do that for you automatically. Just add `[UIHint("PersianDatePicker")]` as an attribute and it will render and convert the date (https://github.com/VahidN/Mvc-App-Persian-DatePicker/blob/master/MvcAppPersianDatePicker/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PersianDatePicker.cshtml).

Answer (score 3):

I have a created a sample repository for this plugin here @github: https://github.com/VahidN/Mvc-App-Persian-DatePicker

Take a look at its [sample model](https://github.com/VahidN/Mvc-App-Persian-DatePicker/blob/master/MvcAppPersianDatePicker/Models/Post.cs) with `[UIHint("PersianDatePicker")]` which uses `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\PersianDatePicker.cshtml` automatically.

Comment: Your question was about `EditorFor` and `UIHint` is designed for that.

Comment: you are right, I didn't use EditorFor yet. I understood your answer. I will try it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an example for using the solar calendar based on the Telerik Kendo UI calendar, see the link below:

[KendoUI Persian Solar (Shamsi-Jalali) Calendar for Kendo UI in MVC applications.](https://github.com/MahdiNosratian/KendoUI-Persian-Calendar-MVC)

**Note:** Using these files, you can use kendoDatePicker and kendoCalendar **(English and Persian) together**.